# Understanding Drupal PHP Error Log

Tags: php, drupal

My developer team at General Motors has no PHP experience but we have to help with a Drupal/PHP site that went down.  I took the 10 lines from the error logs that look important.  Could anyone help us understand what's happening from these 10 lines?  Any help is appreciated.

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'hash' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jul 23 11:30:04 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8j-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 11:30:05 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Warning:  Module 'hash' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jul 23 11:30:05 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8j-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 11:30:39 2017] [error] [client 198.208.85.51] ALERT - possible memory corruption detected - unknown Hashtable destructor (attacker '198.208.85.51', file '/www/theblog/index.php', line 19), referer: https://theblog.com/
[Sun Jul 23 22:18:58 2017] [error] Hostname theblock.com. provided via SNI and hostname theblock.com provided via HTTP are different
[Sun Jul 23 22:18:58 2017] [error] Hostname theblock.com. provided via SNI and hostname theblock.com provided via HTTP are different
[Sun Jul 23 22:59:46 2017] [error] [client 198.208.85.51] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /www/theblock/modules/filter/filter.module on line 1123
[Sun Jul 23 23:07:21 2017] [error] [client 198.208.85.51] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /www/theblock/modules/filter/filter.module on line 1123
```

Comment: There is a fatal error, shown in the error log. [Sun Jul 23 22:59:46 2017] [error] [client 198.208.85.51] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /www/theblock/modules/filter/filter.module on line 1123. This is your main culprit. getElementsByTagName() is a JavaScript method which is being invoked in PHP.

Comment: Probably a DOMDocument:: getElementsByTagName() error and not a JS, this may be an XML that is not being loaded properly (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: sorry for the mistake. @Gustavo Jantsch is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Recollecting what was last done might help to resolve your issue. Since in apache error log the showing issue in filter module, check for latest text format if you have updated. (The failing point is when conversion happens from a DOM object back to an HTML snippet). Also verify if you have installed any new module prior to this failure.(if yes try to disable that module using db)